# Express JS - unable to center text in a DIV in a pug template with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am working on an Express JS web app based on Bootstrap 4 styling as front-end.

No custom stylesheet is involved.

My HTML with Bootstrap 4 styling:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="grid-container">
                <div><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="items/addItem">Add a New Item</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="grid-container">
                <div><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="items/showItemList?status=0">Originated items</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="grid-container">
                <div><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="items/showItemList?status=1">Equipment Catelogue</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="grid-container">
                <div><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="items/showItemList?status=4">Items removed from service</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="grid-container">
                <div><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="items/showItemList?status=3">Items Under Evaluation</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="grid-container">
                <div><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="items/showItemList?status=5">Evalutaion Completed but not proceed</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would need to center the text in each DIV element in the grid-container. However, they are all top aligned as below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a vertical-align, and there are multiple ways to get this done.

Here is one of them

```css
div.center.middle {
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 85px;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="center middle">
  Test text
</div>
```

Note that in order for the `vertical-align: center` to work I had to set the `display: table-cell;`.